# Android Studio: Is not showing the complete productivity guide

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried finding the error online but looks like no-one has this problem. I really love android studio tips at its starting. But it's not showing full guide. Is there anyway to rectify it or do I need to reinstall android studio: I don't want to do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9HXN.png)